# What is a "dry crisp sandwich"?

Tags: meaning

The BBC article [Bradford school bans sausage rolls from packed lunches](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-leeds-41412911) quotes a father saying:

> He ended up eating a dry crisp sandwich. How is that any healthier?

What does that mean?

Comment: I assume butterless.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth aren't most sandwiches butterless? Plus, since he says "how is that any healther?" it sounds like a "dry crisp sandwich" is something unhealthy.

Comment: Not in my experience, but even if that's not generally true, why should that mean there isn't a term meaning 'not buttered'? / There is doubtless context showing a comparison, probably with sausage rolls, which you have for some reason omitted here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok, so "dry" means "butterless" and "crisp" means "potato chip"?

Comment: 'Dry sandwich' is probably a dialect usage, and certainly may be used with the more obvious sense, but 'crisp' is BrE for AmE 'potato chip'.

Comment: "dry" would be understood in at least most American delis as not only butterless but without mayo or mustard or any other condiments.

Comment: @Xanne I never knew that, and my first job was stocking the mayo and mustard aisle of an American grocery store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potato chips are known as crisps in the UK.

A dry crisp sandwich is two slices of bread, unbuttered, with potato chips as the filling of the sandwich. This is by no means an unusual thing in the UK.

See [crisp sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisp_sandwich) and [other variations](http://doyouwanttohearmore.blogspot.fr/2015/01/crisp-sandwich.html).

Comment: @DavePhD: Actually, they're quite nice. But not something I'd have every day!

Comment: I guess I should try it first before saying "disgusting".  I'm imagining the top of my mouth being poked by pointy chips.

Comment: Yes, you do have to crush the crisps down a little, or you risk laceration. But depending which flavour crisps you choose, the result can be surprisingly nice.

Comment: @DavePhD Tayto Cheese & Onion crisp sandwich ... 